# Different macro behavior when used in another macro

Tags: macros, boxes, expansion

Please consider the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mymargin}{\hspace*{3em}}
\newcommand{\innerbox}[1]{\mymargin\fbox{#1}\mymargin}
\newcommand{\outerbox}[1]{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

test \innerbox{Hello} test% OK

test \outerbox{\innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello}}%   I don't want space at beginning and end of box

test \outerbox{\fbox{Hello}\mymargin{} test \innerbox{Hello} test \mymargin\fbox{Hello}}%   what i'd like

\end{document}
```

(actually, the definitions of boxes are more complex but I think that doesn't change anything to the logic)

I'd like the use of `\innerbox` inside `\outerbox` not to induce spaces at the beginning and at the end of the box.

I suppose i should expand argument `#1` (once got rid of the unnecessary spaces) from `\outerbox` and detect if the first and last token are equal `\mymargin` and then make the necessary changes but I really don't know how to do it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check (ignoring spaces) whether the first token in the argument of `\outerbox` is `\innerbox` and, in this case, insert a negative space for compensation.

At the end you can recursively remove all glue nodes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mymarginwidth}{3em}
\newcommand{\mymargin}{\hspace*{\mymarginwidth}}
\newcommand{\negmymargin}{\hspace*{-\mymarginwidth}}

\newcommand{\innerbox}[1]{\mymargin\fbox{#1}\mymargin}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\outerbox}[1]{%
  \fbox{%
    \@ifnextchar\innerbox{\negmymargin}{}#1%
    \forever@unskip
  }%
}
\newcommand{\forever@unskip}{%
  \ifnum\lastnodetype=11
    \expandafter\unskip\expandafter\forever@unskip
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

test \innerbox{Hello} test

test \outerbox{\innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello}}

test \outerbox{\fbox{Hello}\mymargin{} test \innerbox{Hello} test \mymargin\fbox{Hello}}

test \outerbox{test \innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello}}

test \outerbox{\innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello} test}

test \outerbox{ test \innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello} }

test \outerbox{ \innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello} test }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly well... for this example of use. But, actually, `\innerbox` is defined with an optional argument (as `\newcommand{\innerbox}[2][]{...}`) and, in this case, your code leads to an error : `! Use of \\innerbox doesn't match its definition.`. What should i change in your code to have it work ?

Comment: @user30654 Added the code

Comment: Your new code is all working fine, thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

This version omits the space if `\innerbox` is in any hbox, not just `\outerbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mymargin}{\hspace*{3em}}
\newcommand{\innerbox}[1]{\ifhmode\ifinner\else\mymargin\fi\fi\fbox{#1}\ifhmode\ifinner\else\mymargin\fi\fi}
\newcommand{\outerbox}[1]{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

test \innerbox{Hello} test% OK

test \outerbox{\innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello}}%   I don't want space at beginning and end of box

test \outerbox{\fbox{Hello}\mymargin{} test \innerbox{Hello} test \mymargin\fbox{Hello}}%   what i'd like

\end{document}
```

egreg notes  that you may not be what you wanted, so..

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mymargin}{\hspace*{3em}}
\newcommand{\innerbox}[1]{\ifhmode\ifnum\lastpenalty=-1\else\mymargin\fi\fi\fbox{#1}\mymargin}
\newcommand{\outerbox}[1]{\fbox{\penalty-1#1\unskip\unskip}}

\begin{document}

test \innerbox{Hello} test% OK

test \outerbox{\innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello} test \innerbox{Hello}}%   I don't want space at beginning and end of box

test \outerbox{\fbox{Hello}\mymargin{} test \innerbox{Hello} test \mymargin\fbox{Hello}}%   what i'd like

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which is rather different from the output the OP seems to want. Look at the “what I'd like” line.

Comment: @egreg 2nd version added (shame, first version was more fun)